# React/Redux props property of store is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my app I'm using:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.24.5",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
},
```

**On the redux side I have this setup:**
store.js:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './reducers';
const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middleware));

export default store;
```

rootReducer is:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

import menuReducer from './menuReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  menu: menuReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Which has only menuReducer in its disposal:

```
import * as types from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  data: {}
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.GET_MENU:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Which gets it's feed from a single menu action:

```
import * as types from './types';

export const getMenu = () => (dispatch) => {
  fetch('/admin/json/menu.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => dispatch({
      type: types.GET_MENU,
      payload: data
    })
  )
}
```

**And finally the on the components side I have:**
App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import store from '../store';
import SideMenu from './sidemenu';
import Content from './content';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter basename='/yonetim'>
          <div className="h-100">
            <SideMenu className="h-100"/>
            <Content className="h-100"/>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  };
};

export default App;
```

And the component which tries to consume this basic redux implementation:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import {v1 as uuid} from 'uuid';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {getMenu} from '../actions/menuActions';
import MenuDropdown from './parts/menu-dropdown';
import MenuItem from './parts/menu-item';

class SideMenu extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getMenu();
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.menuData);
    return(
      <header>
        <div className="cnt-menu-head">
          <h6>{this.props.menuData.heading}</h6>
        </div>
        <div className="cnt-menu">
          <ul className="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            {this.props.menuData.sections.map((section, i) => {
              if (section.type === 'link') {
                let key = uuid();
                return <MenuItem key={key} exact={section.exact} linkTo={section.linkTo} linkText={section.linkText}/>
              } else if (section.type === 'dropdown') {
                let keyedLinks = section.links.map((link) => {
                  link.key = uuid();
                  return link;
                });
                return (
                  <Fragment key={uuid()}>
                    <div className="horizontal-separator"></div>
                    <MenuDropdown linkText={section.linkText} links={keyedLinks}/>
                  </Fragment>
                )
              }
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  };
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    menuData: state.menu.data
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getMenu})(SideMenu);
```

**What happens is:**

I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

refering to `this.props.menuData.sections.map()` part of my code. Now the funny thing is:

1. The render function of this component gets called twice
2. When I put `console.log()` in both the action and reducer I see they get called twice as well.
3. When I comment out the codes that try to use `this.props.menuData` in `render()` then `console.log(this.props.menuData);` at the beginning of render function prints empty in the first run of `render()` and then gets filled with the actual data I'm trying to use with the second run. I have absolutely no idea what's going on with this code or what may be the underlying cause. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're calling an "async" action (fetch) which dispatch the data after fetching.

So your component loads but then when your function (getMenu) dispatch the action down to Redux, your component run for the second time.

I may suggest to do a ternary which conditions the render of the consumer of menuData and show a loader:

Inside your render:

```
return this.props.menuData.sections ? (actualCodeGoesHere) : <Loader />
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Can you explain why the multiple call of methods? When I put `console.log` on various places I get these series of redundant calls: Menu reducer, Menu reducer, Menu reducer, Menu action, Running render, Menu reducer, Running render

Comment: First, I would recommend to use `componentDidMount` over `componentWillMount`, the second one is now deprecated. Try to do so, and put a `console.log` in there to test if gets called twice, if so, it doesn't have to do with the component nor reducer, it must be something else, maybe the router, let me know if the `console.log` fires twice inside a `componentDidMount`

Comment: I get 1 log in `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` also has one, but `render` has two. I'm guessing you're right. `BrowserRouter` may be re-rendering the `SideMenu` component after `Content` which has the routes defined gets rendered. Because I get .....,Running router, Menu will mount, Menu action, Running render, Running content, Menu did mount, Menu reducer, Running render

Comment: To avoid overcalling the action, you could call it from inside your app component. Which shouldn't be a problem thanks to Redux, it will just populate SideMenu, or add a flag to prevent future calls, hope it was helpful, luck!

Answer (score 1):

sure, you don't have data at the first time render. there are two ways to fix this:
1. put the sections key to the initialState for the menuReducer.
2. add a detection before this.props.menuData.sections.map(…). maybe like this: this.props.menuData.sections && this.props.menuData.sections.map(…)